# WordPress "Next Post" URL and Thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a noobie. Building my new theme. I need to get 3 separate data:

- direct link to the next post thumb
- Next post name
- Next post URL

Thank you for any help)

My code dosent work:

```
<div class="post" style="background: url(<?php next_image_link(); ?>) no-repeat center center;">
    <span></span>
    <div class="title">
<h1>
   <a href="<?php next_post_link(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h1></div>
```

Comment: next_image_link()  and use next_post_link( $link);

Comment: Tried "<?php previous_image_link( 'fullsize' ); ?>" didn't get anything.... <?php echo previous_image_link(); ?> also dosent work...

Comment: do you set size for 'fullsize'

Comment: without size still doent work(

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: added to the post :)